# How do we call a statement that is unthinkable for any person to not be the case?

Tags: epistemology, truth, axiom

The example of such an unthinkable or unimaginable thing for a person could be non-existence, therefore argument against existence seems to be so absurd. Aren't we calling such things axioms or postulates?

Comment: Not clear... The text speaks of an "an unthinkable or unimaginable thing", in which case how we can "name" an unthinkable thing ?

Comment: While the title is more convoluted : "a statement that is unthinkable/ unimaginable for a person to not be the case" that sounds like (but I may be wrong) that a person cannot fail to think...

Comment: I meant: A statement that is unthinkable or unimaginable for a person to not be the case.

Comment: In other words: We argue that something is the case and we cannot imagine any possible case in which the it is not the case. My question is than: How do we call such a statement for which it is unthinkable for a person to not be the case?

Comment: Obviously not a postulate: we can imagine for Euclid's fifth postulate  to not be the case (and we have imagined it...).

Comment: Maybe the old concept of [Laws of thought](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_thought) : we cannot imagine to think in a way different from the way we think. But also this concept has been put in discussion with so-called non-classical logics.

Comment: One example of such a statement that I am particularly interested in is the following: It is unthinkable for a person to not be the case that we could know something for sure since it is impossible to know with certainty that we know everything (which implies that we don't know anything for sure).

Comment: What does it mean "(un)thinkable" ? You are writing it... Whatever you can express is thinkable. And how you can express/communicate something that you "cannot think" ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant: It is unthinkable for a person to think of any case in which he would get any information that would make him absolutely certain. Even if I had for example all the knowledge of the universe I couldn't be certain that that's all I can know and therefore still I could not be certain with any statement I want to make.

Comment: Let me paraphrase the example of such a statement again: "It is unthinkable for a person to imagine any information that would make him absolutely certain that the information is the case."

Comment: Are you talking about something like [Moore sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_paradox), where the implied context contradicts what is being said, e.g. "*It's raining but I do not think that it is*"? Or we can not imagine that nothing exists because then we would not be talking about it? Such things are called [pragmatic paradoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contradiction#Pragmatic_contradictions), and they are used to argue against philosophical positions that are pragmatically inconsistent. But "I know something but I do not know everything" is not one of them.

Comment: Actually I am not sure. It seems to me that neither of two of you examples characterize the meaning of what I am meaning. I am asking on the following: Is there any name by which we call a statement for which we cannot think of any scenario by which we would disprove such a statement. For example, I cannot think of any scenario in which I could know any information that would make me certain that I really know everything about a particular subject.

Comment: The question might need revision for clarity. Was there a specific situation that brought this question to mind?

Answer (score 0):

Such a thing is not in general an axiom or postulate.  Such an idea can be complex and non-foundational.  Humans may not be able to actually imagine that there are countably many Real numbers.  But to get to that point requires a lot of leverage.  No one would consider that an axiom.

More formally, very few such things are axioms.  For if you had two or more ideas that cannot be imagined to be false, their combination would also be such a thing.  The combination of two axioms is never an axiom.

I think that what you are after are simply *necessary* propositions, statements in the modality of "must", the content of the standard modal logic selected by the 'box' operator, facts true in all possible worlds (however one chooses to name this content.)

If you mean a specific person, and not a general person, this is the variant of that modality where the relevant attached context for necessity (or set of possible worlds, or visibility filter on the possible worlds (again depending on your model of a modal)) is determined by that individual's mental configuration rather than by "natural" possibility.